# Changed JSF-Implementation in Tomcat. From Mojarra to MyFaces. Managed-Beans does not work

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, myfaces

I'm using Tomcat-7.0.33 which has the built-in jsf-implementation Mojarra. Is that right?

I want to move to Apache MyFaces.
What i did, to achieve this:

**I've removed from /WEB-INF/lib/**

1. jsf-api-2.1.7
2. jsf-impl-2.1.7

**Added in /WEB-INF/lib/:**

1. myfaces-api-2.1.10
2. myfaces-impl-2.1.10
3. plus the 5 apache commons-jars

**So my completly /lib-folder:**

1. commons-beanutils-1.8.3
2. commons-codec-1.3
3. commons-collections-3.2
4. commons-digester-1.8
5. commons-logging-1.1.1
6. gson-2.2.2
7. jstl-1.2
8. myfaces-api-2.1.10
9. myfaces-impl-2.1.10
10. prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3
11. primefaces-3.4

I'm using Eclipse 4.2 (Juno). **I've cleaned the Tomcat-Server.**

When i request one of my pages, everything looks fine (even the source).
But my Managed-Beans does not work. Seems that JSF don't register/find them.

I guess i don't need to post my faces or beans here, because with mojarra it works fine.

Comment: Note: Tomcat doesn't ship with any JSF implementation built-in. You've provided it yourself in flavor of those `jsf-api` and `jsf-impl` JAR files. If Tomcat had it builtin, you wouldn't have the need to provide any JSF JAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyFaces is conflicting with another instance of itself. The `myfaces-bundle.jar` already contains both the API and impl. You need to include *either*

- `myfaces-api.jar`
- `myfaces-impl.jar`

*or*

- `myfaces-bundle.jar`

but not both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Oh, you're right, but it didn't solved the problem. I removed the myfaces-bundle from the /lib folder and cleaned  everything. Still these message..

Comment: The log messages are not the problem. They are purely informal. You said that it "does not work" and after removing the duplicate JAR, it should work fine.

Comment: Or, if you still have a problem, please elaborate it in more detail.

Comment: Even the last log-messsage? With "no state saving method" ? Because my  managed-bean get's not invoked. Ok, i'll add some details and edit my post.

Comment: Those are just informal messages. MyFaces is just setting some default values (which are the same in Mojarra by the way, it only doesn't log them as INFO, but with lower level). Only if you've a SEVERE/ERROR or FATAL, then you've indeed a problem. Do you have this in the log?

Comment: NO ERROR/FATAL/SEVERE. See small update above. Just my beans does not work. With Mojarra it works fine. If you need some other details, let me know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23057/discussion-between-timo-and-balusc)

Comment: Do you have a `faces-config.xml`? If so, is it properly declared conform JSF 2.x version?

Comment: Yes. Version is 2.0. Tried Version 2.1. Same behavior.

Comment: Well, this is weird. What if you create a brand new dynamic web project with a minimum of configuration? I.e. just the faces servlet in `web.xml`, no `faces-config.xml` file and a "Hello World" view+bean?

Comment: Then it works. So i guess it's up to me to find the difference. Thanks so far again.